# airplay adk for iPhone development

Tags: ios4

how to create ***hello world*** iPhone application using ***airplay sdk***  in mac osx.

I just installed in my mac.. is there any setting change is required ?

pls help me by giving the procedure..

thanks and regards..

Comment: did you get the solution  even i am trying the same..